# can't load rethinkdb http administrative console

Tags: port, rethinkdb

I had rethinkDB working in the last days.My pc upgraded to windows 10 so the http admin console couldn't load anymore, although the server is launched: I get `server is ready`, when I launch localhost:8080 the pages keeps on loading but nothing happens . I've changed the port with -o option ;then --http-port but negative.

Answer (score -2):

I got it working back by downgrading to windows 7